# Can values from IPython widgets propagate to other cells?

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to have values from IPython widgets propagate to other cells without reloading those cells further downstream?

Specifically, I have some check boxes which indicate whether to plot certain lines in each chart. I have several charts and I'd like to have the charts in separate cells so that I can provide text descriptions of what's in each plot. The rough structure of what I'm envisioning is shown below, with each numbered item in the list is a different cell.

1. Markdown - Select each of the lines you want to plot from the checkboxes below.
2. Code - `interactive(some_plotting_fn, ckbox1=CheckboxWidget(), ckbox2=CheckboxWidget())`
3. Markdown - Description of first chart. Blah blah.
4. Code - `plot_first_chart_based_on_check_boxes()`
5. Markdown - Description of second chart. Blah blah blah.
6. Code - `plot_second_chart_based_on_check_boxes()`

Is that feasible? I could do all the plotting in a single cell, but then the plots end up bunched together and I'd prefer to have text describing the charts to introduce them.

Comment: The callbacks called when your widgets update can do anything, but any output created will be displayed in the same cell as the widget, not in other cells. If you needed to get round that, you could draw the plots using more widgets, and update them in response to changes in the checkboxes - but that's probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: @thomas-k Could you sketch out what that would look like, drawing the plots using more widgets?

Comment: I don't know of any tools that draw plots in widgets at the moment. You would need a Python piece that stored a representation of the plot in traitlets, and a Javascript piece that could take that representation and draw it.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `checkbox` as separate objects :

```
from IPython.html.widgets import interactive, Checkbox
c= Checkbox()
interactive(lambda x,y: print(x,y), x=c, y=Checkbox())
----
display X and Y checkbox
```

Here some markdown....

```
interactive(lambda x,y: print(x,z), x=c, z=Checkbox())
----
display X and Z checkbox
```

Here more markdown, I won't use interactive, so you will need to rerun the cell to see changes :

```
if x is True:
   title('is is True')
plot(...)
```

The X checkbox is synced across cells (on IPython master at least) 
replace the print by your plotting functions. You can also access the value of 'x' by `c.value` .

[edit] To respond to people proposind edits:  Note that on IPython master and future versions the `Widget` suffix has been dropped. The API with suffixes everywhere was provisional and never ment to be definitive. So the correct usage is indeed `Checkbox` and not `CheckboxWidget`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this visually works (the checkboxes check on and off in sync), but the underlying data remains the same. If you run your example, you'll see that when you check "x" the value in the other cell doesn't change despite the checkbox changing status.

Comment: Hum, indeed, probably a bug, investigating.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same effect with other widgets, like `RadioButtons`. I also get the same effect if I use a regular `container` with `on_trait_change` instead of `interactive`. It seems like the trait change only registers within the cell in which the action happens.